# Is there a way to use the "stickyHeaderIndices" prop for SectionList like it is used for FlatList in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-sectionlist

I'm trying to get the top header of my SectionList (not the individual section headings) to stick on the page, so other items are allowed to scroll underneath.

The prop "stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}" does the intended job on FlatList, but not SectionList. Is there an easy workaround for this?

Comment: If you have a single static header maybe put it in its own view above the sectionlist instead of rendering it as part of the list. I don't believe what you're asking for is possible with SectionList alone if you also want other section headers.